JS how to target a div inside of the clicked div
Kind of a special case of this: Change CSS of the clicked element.
If I have some divs like this:


    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>

     <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>


    

I know I can assign a function to each parent div like:
const parent = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');
if(parent.length){
   for (let l of parent){
      l.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        l.classList.toggle('visible')
      })
   }
}

But how can I toggle the class .visible for the child div when the parent is clicked? Or alternatively add visibility:visible to the child div style.
Many thanks!

You can use e.target for this then check if this target contains the .parent class then select its children with .child using e.target.querySelector to toggle the desired class.


const parent = document.querySelectorAll('.parent')
// console.log(parent)

parent.forEach(div=>{
    div.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
        let target = e.target
        // console.log(target)
        if(e.target.matches('.parent')){
            const children = e.target.querySelector('.child')
            children.classList.toggle('changeBackground')
        }
    })
})
.parent{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height:  100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.child{
    display: flex;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.child.changeBackground{
    background-color: yellow;
}
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>

     <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>




I think OP want the child visibility to toggle when clicking the parent div

Finaly I think so. I am updating my code :-)

You can continue using querySelector, but this time start searching from your parent element, instead of from document.
parent.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  // `event.currentTarget` gives you element that event listener attached to.
  // it's not necessary, but I prefer to do this way.
  const child = event.currentTarget.querySelector(".child");
  // since `querySelector` can return `null`, it's never bad thing to check
  // using optional chaining is also a solution
  if (child === null) return;
  child.classList.toggle("visible");
});

A bit of advice - it's better to use buttons as interactive elements, since div doesn't have any semantics and doesn't show as an interactive element in accessibility tree. Also it can't be activated with a keyboard. This makes your element inaccessible for some users. Using button will require only changing HTML and will make this much more usable.

This will toggle just the first child, i think OP wants all the children to be toggled

No this is what I wanted to do. And thanks for the advice, I always thought it seemed unintuitive to have to remove the button formatting every time but it makes sense.

Within the event listener, you can target the child element of the clicked parent and toggle a class or modify its style directly. Here’s how to do it
<div class="parent">  
    <div class="child"></div>  
</div>  

<div class="parent">  
    <div class="child"></div>  
</div>  

<style>  
    .child {  
        visibility: hidden; /* Initially hidden */  
    }  
    .child.visible {  
        visibility: visible; /* Visible when the class '.visible' is added */  
    }  
</style>  

<script>  
    const parents = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');  
    if (parents.length) {  
        for (let parent of parents) {  
            parent.addEventListener('click', () => {  
                const child = parent.querySelector('.child'); // Select the child  
                child.classList.toggle('visible'); // Toggle the class  
            });  
        }  
    }  
</script>  


I think the simplest way to ensure only clicks on the .parent elements toggle the .visible class on the .child elements would be to check if e.target is not the e.currentTarget. If true then just do an early return from the addEventListener callback function. Otherwise toggle the .visible class on the .child element. Note, this assumes only one .child element per .parent.
An example would be:


const parents = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');
if(parents.length){
   for (let p of parents){
      p.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
         if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
         e.target.querySelector('.child').classList.toggle('visible')
      })
   }
}
section{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
 }
.parent{
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   background: black;
   margin: 0.5rem;
   padding: 1.5rem;
}
.child{
   padding: 0.5rem;
   background: blue;
   color: white;
   visibility: hidden;
}
.visible{
   visibility: visible;
}
<section>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">Box 1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">Box 2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">Box 3</div>
   </div>
</section>



